# Specflow Association with .feature Files

Tags: specflow

I have installed Specflow via Nuget, but .feature files do not appear to be associated with Specflow. The `TechTalk.Specflow` DLL is present in the references for the DLL containing my tests.

Right clicking on a feature file and selecting `Run Tests` results in a dialog `No tests found in file.`

Can anyone help me diagnose this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nuget package gives you everything you need to run SpecFlow tests, but there is a separate installation @ [The Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9915524d-7fb0-43c3-bb3c-a8a14fbd40ee) which gives you the design time integration includign file associations