# visual studio 2012 add new item does not show test items

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, specflow, vs-unit-testing-framework

I installed VS 2012 Ultimate on a Windows 2008 server and ran all the updates. However, when I create a C# Windows form application and the click on Add New Item I don't see any of the test item templates (the list under Visual C# Items contains only Code, Data, General, Web, Windows Forms, WPF, Reporting and Workflow). Also, after adding SpecFlow via Nuget Package Manager, I don't see the Specflow items.

I had this working on another system, but can't see why these items fail to get added to the Add New Items dialog
Robert

Comment: I have run devenv /setup and devenv /installvstemplates with no effect.

Comment: This is normal, the dialog is context sensitive.  You'll only get the test items when you try to add them to a Test project.

Comment: That does not explain why the Specflow items don't show.

Comment: That's why it is always a bad idea to ask two questions at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The nuget package gives you everything you need to run SpecFlow tests, but there is a separate installation @ [The Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9915524d-7fb0-43c3-bb3c-a8a14fbd40ee) which gives you the design time integration including file associations.

(This part of your question is a duplicate of [Specflow Association with .feature Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231587/specflow-association-with-feature-files))